# Error: Warning: ini_set(): A session is active

Tags: reports, cron

I am requesting Reports via Cron to email:
https://crm.xxx.lv/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?pass=xxx&name=xxx&key=xxxx&job=mail_report&format=csv&instanceId=70

All reports work just fine, except for one which returns the following error when I run the address in browser.

Before there was an identical report (Constituent Summary) which just disappeared from system somehow. When I created identical new report, this error came up.

How can I solve it?

CiviCRM 4.7.14. on Drupal

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My fault. The issue seems to be caused by wrong Permission in Access settings in Report.

Instead of using **CiviCRM: View all contacts** it was set to **CiviReport: Access CiviReport**.